# oracle 10g IN clause query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-01722

Please ignore obvious syntax flaws in the below:

I have an sql like this as a named query:

```
select saalry from emp where emp_id in (:id)
```

id is of type number
I wanted to pass in a comma separated list like this:

```
String id = 121,123,456
```

But I am getting `ORA-01722: invalid number`
How can I pass a comma separated list of ids to my IN clause?

Comment: you say `id is of type number` but you're passing it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `:id` is a string containing a relatively short comma-delimited list of numbers (e.g. `'123,456,789'`), this may be sufficient for you:

```
select saalry from emp
where INSTR( ',' || :id || ','
           , ',' || TRIM(TO_CHAR(emp_id)) || ','
           ) > 0;
```

It won't perform as well, however, since it is unlikely to use an index on `emp_id`.

Comment: The answer is good enough, although I'd use collections and the TABLE operator so an index can be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that is from http://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Their example is

```
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Which can be put into an in clause

```
 select * from emp where ename in (
   select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
   connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );
```